# Why this method doesn't want to be executed more than 1 times per line

Tags: java, methods

On my theory this code should print a triangle of stars, in this case 5 lines each line will have 1 more star than the line before it, but in reality it prints 5 lines on 1 stars why ?

```
public class Main {

private static void printStars(int amount){
    System.out.print("*");
    }
private static void printTriangle(int size){
    int i = 0;
    int b = 0;
    while (size > i){
        printStars(b);
        System.out.println("");
        b++;
    i++;        
    }
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
    printTriangle(5);
    }}
```

Comment: `private static void printStars(int amount)` are you sure about this? Where do you use `amount`...?

Comment: Add a loop in `printStars`: `for(int i = 0; i<=b; i++) System.out.print("*");`

Answer (score 1):

```
private static void printStars(int amount){
    for(int i=0; i<amount+1; i++)
        System.out.print("*");
}
```

Comment: Nicer is: `System.out.print(Strings.repeat("*", amount));` or `System.out.print(StringUtils.repeat("*", amount));`